# Unable to POST request using guzzle with the Amadeus API

Tags: php, laravel, amadeus

**Description**
I am trying to integrate Amadeus Self-Service API within the Laravel Environment. I am successfully able to get content by `GET` request, but I am not able to get content by the `POST` request. I have set the exceptions to display the errors thrown by the guzzle in specific.

Here is the api reference, which has the data and the endpoint which I want to post to.
https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference

**How to reproduce**
This is the method which I call from my Client.php and pass the data through by calling the POST method.

```
public function __construct() {
    throw_if(static::$instance, 'There should be only one instance of this class');
    static::$instance = $this;
    $this->client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/',
    ]);
}

public function get($uri, array $options = []) {
    $this->authenticate();
    return $this->client->request('GET', $uri, [
        $options, 
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->access_token,
        ],
    ]);
}

public function post($uri, array $options = []) {
    $this->authenticate();
    return $this->client->request('POST', $uri, [
        $options, 
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->access_token,
        ],
    ]);
}
```

After calling the POST method, I pass the 'X-HTTP-Method-Override' as 'GET', and pass the data as body.

```
$requests_response = $client->post('v2/shopping/flight-offers', [
    'headers' => [
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override' => 'GET',
    ],
    'body' => [
        [
            "currencyCode" => "USD",
            "originDestinations" => [
                [
                    "id" => "1",
                    "originLocationCode" => "RIO",
                    "destinationLocationCode" => "MAD",
                    "departureDateTimeRange" => [
                        "date" => "2022-11-01",
                        "time" => "10:00:00",
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    "id" => "2",
                    "originLocationCode" => "MAD",
                    "destinationLocationCode" => "RIO",
                    "departureDateTimeRange" => [
                        "date" => "2022-11-05",
                        "time" => "17:00:00",
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            "travelers" => [
                ["id" => "1", "travelerType" => "ADULT"],
                ["id" => "2", "travelerType" => "CHILD"],
            ],
            "sources" => ["GDS"],
            "searchCriteria" => [
                "maxFlightOffers" => 2,
                "flightFilters" => [
                    "cabinRestrictions" => [
                        [
                            "cabin" => "BUSINESS",
                            "coverage" => "MOST_SEGMENTS",
                            "originDestinationIds" => ["1"],
                        ],
                    ],
                    "carrierRestrictions" => [
                        "excludedCarrierCodes" => ["AA", "TP", "AZ"],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

**Additional context**
Here is the error, which I caught in the log.

```
local.ERROR: Guzzle error {"response":{"GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream":"
    {
        \"errors\": [
            {
                \"code\": 38189,
                \"title\": \"Internal error\",
                \"detail\": \"An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator\",
                \"status\": 500
            }
        ]
    }
"}}


local.ERROR: Server error: POST https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error response:
{
"errors": [
"code": 38189,
(truncated...)
"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ServerException(code: 500): Server error: POST https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error response:

"errors": [
"code": 38189,
(truncated...)
at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Application\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Exception\\RequestException.php:113)
```

Please spare some time to have a look, help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the POST calls actually work using a HTTP client such as Postman or Insomnia ?

I am noticing is that you are passing an array of `$options` and are nesting it inside the Guzzle options. The resulting call will look something like this:

```
$this->client->request('POST', $uri, [
   ['headers' => '...', 'body' => ['...']],
   'headers' => ['...']
]);
```

That won't work, you are going to need to unpack them this way:

```
public function post($uri, array $options = []) {
   $this->authenticate();
   return $this->client->request('POST', $uri, [
       ...$options, 
       'headers' => [
           'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->access_token,
       ],
   ]);
}
```

Notice the dots `...` to unpack the options array. Also notice that you are setting the `headers` key twice (once in your post method definition and once in the options parameter), so only one will actually be used (by the way why exactly are you using the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header ?).

Another solution if you want to pass all header and body in the POST function parameters is this:

```
public function post($uri, array $options = []) {
   $this->authenticate();
   return $this->client->request('POST', $uri, [
       'json' => $options['json'], // I would suggest 'json' because it looks like the API is looking for a JSON body, if that doesn't work go with 'body' 
       'headers' => [
           'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->access_token,
           ...$options['headers']
       ],
   ]);
}
```

Another thing you might try if this doesn't do it is using the Guzzle `json` option instead of `body` for the POST request.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the response, actually `X-HTTP-Method-Override` is being used to force a get request while posting the data to the endpoint. This is mentioned by the amadeus itself on their api reference. Please check the reference within the post option. I am confused, by how should I send the data to the endpoint. https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference

Comment: Okay got it :) i'll edit my answer to give you something that should work better for you

Comment: Its just perfect my friend, thanks alot. Just want to ask If I don't put the ` X-HTTP-Method-Override` it still works, so what's the difference? Just for facts.

Comment: Perfect :D, well i honestly don't have the slightest clue of what that header actually does and why Amadeus says it requires it .. Maybe it's for their documentation or something

Answer (score 0):

when you are exploring any Amadeus Self Service API, I recommend to review the portal, because it will help you with one idea about how to make the http calls.

In your case:
https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference

Another help could be to review the coding examples:

- https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-code-examples/blob/master/flight_offers_search/v2/post/curl/
- https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-code-examples/tree/master/flight_offers_search/v2/get/curl

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have gone through it thoroughly. The problem is I want to do that using guzzle and not curl. There is an example of `GET` request for the PHP but not `POST`. That's the main reason I am posting the question here.

Comment: Guzzle has a more ergonomic api but you add a new dependency in your project. Consider it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little late but this example work for me:

```
$options = [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => sprintf('Bearer %s', $this->getApiToken()),
            'content-type'        => 'application/vnd.amadeus+json',
            'X-HTTP-Method-Override' => 'GET',
        ],
        'body' => '{
                "currencyCode": "XPF",
                "originDestinations": [
                    {
                                  "id": 1,
                        "originLocationCode": "PPT",
                        "originRadius": null,
                        "alternativeOriginsCodes": [],
                        "destinationLocationCode": "CDG",
                        "alternativeDestinationsCodes": [],
                        "departureDateTimeRange": {
                            "date": "2022-12-22",
                            "dateWindow": "I2D"
                        },
                        "includedConnectionPoints": [],
                        "excludedConnectionPoints": []
                    }
                ],
                "travelers": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "travelerType": "ADULT",
                        "associatedAdultId": null
                    }
                ],
                "sources": [
                    "GDS"
                ]
            }'
    ];

    try {
    ...
        $response = $this->httpClient->post(self::AMADEUS_API_URL_FLIGHT_OFFER, $options);

        $body = $response->getBody();
        ...
```

Note: don't forget the content-type, it's not very obvious at first sight in the documentation but without it doesnt work with Guzzle for me (but with insomnia no problem)

consts of the class:

```
private const AMADEUS_API_CLIENT_GRANT_TYPE = 'client_credentials';

private const AMADEUS_API_URL_AUTH = '/v1/security/oauth2/token';

private const AMADEUS_API_URL_FLIGHT_OFFER = '/v2/shopping/flight-offers';
```

Authentication:

```
    /**
     *
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->getApiToken())) {
            return $this->getApiToken();
        }

        $options = [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => $this->apiId, //setted in the parent construct
                'client_secret' => $this->apiKey, //setted in the parent construct
                'grant_type' => self::AMADEUS_API_CLIENT_GRANT_TYPE,
            ]
        ];

        try {

            $response = $this->httpClient->post(self::AMADEUS_API_URL_AUTH, $options);
        } catch (ClientExceptionInterface $exception) {
            ...
        }


        if ($response->getStatusCode() != Response::HTTP_OK) {
            
            throw new ApiException($errorMessage, [$response->getReasonPhrase()], $response->getStatusCode());
        }

        $body = $response->getBody();
        //custom serializer, AmadeusAuthenticationResponse is a mapping based on Amadeus authentication response
        $authenticationResponse = $this->serializer->convertSerializationToData($body->getContents(), AmadeusAuthenticationResponse::class);

        $this->setApiToken($authenticationResponse->getAccessToken());

        return $this->getApiToken();
    }';
```